# How to properly use QGIS Symbology when operating with foreignkey-linked tables

Tags: qgis

I would like to use the Symbology-Categorized feature in table properties to organize the data representation by attributes. The column in my table contains only the foreign-key of a linked table where the actual value is stored.
Therefor I get only the foreign-key on the Symbology as a result.


[image]


As a workaround I use the Joins feature in table properties to create an additional column with the values from the linked table.

Is there a more elegant solution to solve this?


Thanks,

Anjo